# Why doesn't the Gedo Mazo have tails?

Tags: naruto

If the [Gedo Mazo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Demonic_Statue_of_the_Outer_Path) is the emptied body of the Ten-Tails, then why don't any of its forms look like that?

I have a theory as to why it doesn't have tails, maybe because its chakra was split into the Tailed Beasts and hence it lost its tails. But it still doesn't explain why none of the forms look like that considering that the Gedo Mazo is the way the body looked when [Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki), the Sage of the Six Paths, sealed its empty body inside the moon with [Chibaku Tensei (Planetary Devastation)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chibaku_Tensei).

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: Please don't include spoiler warnings in the title. Use spoiler markdown in the body `>!` if you are worried about spoilers.

Comment: Sorry how do i do that

Comment: In the question or answer body type: `>! Write your content here` the `Write your content here` part will be hidden unless someone roll over that area.

Answer (score 2):

The Gedo Mazo is just a recipient.
The body of Ten Tails is on the moon, Rikudou sent his body there.

I think Madara and Obito plans to take the chakra of the Juubi in the Gedo Mazo, the recipient, and put it back into the real body of Ten tails.

Comment: could you please provide some links to manga chapter and/or external sites so as to make your answer more substantial. \

Comment: I think it is more likely than not to be a creation of shodai hokage. For one thing it is made of wood and shodai controls mokuton.

Comment: More importantly, gedo mazo is seated on a lotus that emanates from a clone of shodai hokage with multiple arms. If you know Hindu mythology, you would know that Brahma is generally depicted seated on a lotus and that he is the creator god. However, Brahma was born out of the lotus that emanated from Vishnu and Vishnu is always depicted with four arms.

Comment: Now, gedo mazo is the source from which the white Zetsu were created and it is seated on a lotus that emanates from shodai's clone. That shodai clone has multiple arms. Put the two together and you have that gedo mazo is modeled after brahma, the god of creation while shodai hokage is modeled after Vishnu, the god with multiple arms.However, gedo mazo emanated from shodai hokage.It has no tails because the tails signify power, and Juubi lost all its chakra, so it's only natural that it lost its tails. Hachibi also lost tails when Killer Bee fought Sasuke, they can grow back if you have chakra.

Comment: With Juubi, it lost all its power and thus all its tails. If you look at the picture of Juubi standing on the lotus, you can see that its trying to grow its tails back but with all the chakra that's pulled out of it by the lotus to grow the Zetsu Army, it can't.

Comment: That's my theory after reading all the manga until now... but according Wiki Naruto
http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Demonic_Statue_of_the_Outer_Path

Comment: @arthur OMG!!!!! Kishimoto did borrowed many concepts from Hindu Mythology....... your speculations are correct since many instances in the Naruto do co-relate with the Hindu divinity........ i initially thought that Rinnegan and the concept of Chakra were the only things they borrowed from Hindu Culture but apparantly Naruto does contain many Hindu  related stuff......good observation though!!

Comment: thanks for all your helpful answers iv been racking my brain trying to figure it out until now but the lost its tails idea is good, i know that it is the body because to quote madara when he awoke the rinnegan it "allowed him to break a certain seal and summon the husk of the juubi from its sealing stone what we call the moon" so the tail theory is the only one that makes sense to me especially if it's trying to grow them back when on the lotus.

Answer (score 0):

The gedo statue doesn't possess any tails because it serves as a "husk" or vessel for all the tailed beasts to reform into their original entity: the Ten Tails. Instead of tails, the gedo statue possesses 9 featureless white eyes that gain pupils for each tailed beast the statue reassimilates. This would make sense since the ten tails eye possesses 9 tomoe that could symbolize each tailed beast assimilated in its base form's eyes.